# LinkLabel doesn't open

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, linklabel

I'm creating LinkLabel in Form2 and Form3 with the same code. Form2 and Form3 are separate classes so the names don't interferer. They are both created, but in the Form 3 links open, in the Form2 nothing happens.

This is the code for Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public void createFormEntry(List<string> videoId)
  {
    LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
    link.Name = "link";
    link.AutoSize = true;
    link.Location = new Point(76, 8);
    link.Text = "www.example.com";
    link.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(link_LinkClicked);
    this.Controls.Add(link);
  }   

    private void link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.example.com");
    }
}
```

And this is for the Form3

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
  private void createFormEntry(Feed<Video> videoFeed)
  {
    LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
    link.Name = "link";
    link.AutoSize = true;
    link.Location = new Point(76, 8);
    link.Text = "www.example.com";
    link.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(link_LinkClicked);
    this.Controls.Add(link);
  }

    private void link_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.example.com");
    }
}
```

They are in different classes. Form2 opens before Form3.
What could be wrong?

EDIT: now when I added more code, I see in Form2 createFormEntry is public and in Form3 it is set as private.
Could that be a reason?

Comment: When link_LinkClicked is declared in Form3 as private void, how can you access it in Form2? Do you have some other code?

Comment: Hi, I edited code, I hope now it's more clear

Comment: Just start your debugger and look where the problem is. I can't find anything in your code snippet. Maybe the important location is somewhere else. Maybe you are using an foreach(AtomEntry in videoFeed) and there are no AtomEntries.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to open a link without telling the program how or what to open that link in. You should tell it to search it in a program or something!

Comment: If it is an URL, Windows starts your default browser. And in Form2 it's all okay